# Prove that $|\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}dx-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}| \leq \frac{3}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Prove that $$|\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}dx-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}| \leq \frac{3}{n!}$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$

I find the Maclaurin expansion of 
$$e^{x^2}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{k!}$$ 
and 
$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{k!}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}dx+\frac{1}{(2n+1)n!}$$ 
so
$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}dx-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}=\frac{1}{(2n+1)n!}$$
How can I explain that $|\frac{1}{(2n+1)n!}| \leq \frac{3}{n!}$?

Comment: The equality $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(2k+1)!}dx+\frac{1}{(2n+1)n!}$ is wrong. How did you get it?

Comment: fixed. $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}dx+\frac{1}{(2n+1)n!}$

Answer (score 1):

The last equality is wrong :
$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}dx=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^{2k}}{k!}dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}dx+\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}$$
So : $$\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}dx-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}=\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+2n+1)(k+n)!}\\=\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+2n+1)(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k)}$$
But :
$$(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k)\geq1.2\dots k=k!$$
$$(2k+2n+1)(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k)\geq k!$$
So :
$$\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+2n+1)(n+1)(n+2)\dots(n+k)}\leq \frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}=\frac{e}{n!}$$
Finally :
$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}dx-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}\leq \frac{e}{n!}\leq\frac3{n!}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}\,dx-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}=\color{red}{\sum_{k\geq n}\frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}}\tag{A}$$
and since
$$ \frac{1}{2k!}-\frac{1}{2(k+1)!} = \frac{k}{(2k+2)k!}\geq\frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}\tag{B} $$
for any $k\geq 2$, we have
$$ \color{red}{0} \leq \left[\int_{0}^{1}e^{x^2}\,dx-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2k+1)k!}\right] \leq \color{red}{\frac{1}{2n!}}\tag{C} $$
for any $n\geq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

That is clear since $1 \le 3 (2n+1)$.

Comment: One of equalities in OPs question is wrong.